How to substract amount of minutes in Pandas DataFrame datetime with condition?
I have a DataFrame like this (date: datetime64[ns], v: float64)
date                   v
2024-09-01 22:09:55    1.2
2024-09-01 22:12:08    1.11
2024-09-01 22:59:59    1.7
2024-09-01 23:00:02    1.1
2024-09-01 23:04:00    2.2

what I want to have is if the minutes in datetime are <= 10 then substract 11 minutes (something like df['date']-timedelta(minutes=11)). Otherwise keep the original datetime.
The expected output should be
date                   v
2024-09-01 21:58:55    1.2
2024-09-01 22:12:08    1.11
2024-09-01 22:59:59    1.7
2024-09-01 22:49:02    1.1
2024-09-01 22:53:00    2.2


Use DataFrame.loc with test minutes by Series.dt.minute and subtract Timedelta:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['2024-09-01 22:09:55',
                                          '2024-09-01 22:12:08',
                                          '2024-09-01 22:59:59',
                                          '2024-09-01 23:00:02',
                                          '2024-09-01 23:04:00']),
                   'v':[1.2,1.11,1.7,1.7,2.2]})

df.loc[df['date'].dt.minute <= 11, 'date'] -= pd.Timedelta('11 Min')
print (df)
                 date     v
0 2024-09-01 21:58:55  1.20
1 2024-09-01 22:12:08  1.11
2 2024-09-01 22:59:59  1.70
3 2024-09-01 22:49:02  1.70
4 2024-09-01 22:53:00  2.20


beautiful! thank you
